Keycloak Create User API returns 403 Forbidden Error
I am getting 403 while trying to create a user through API in keycloak. The error is not coming if “realm_admin”,“manage_users” roles in my client roles are available but it creating issue with the AUD multivalues as the above roles are from other clients. How to overcome this multivalues in aud and create user will also work as success?
I have tried to remove the remove two roles but getting 403 unknown error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
